# Can't access variable from main project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I cannot access the `hi` variable from my library class. Why? Check it out:

[image]

I have this inteface in my library:

```
interface ContextAccessor {

    fun getApplicationContext(): Application?
}
```

And this code as well:

```
class SomeLibraryClass {
    private var mContextAccessor: ContextAccessor?

    String extractedHi = null

    fun setContextAccessor(contextAccessor: ContextAccessor?) {
        mContextAccessor = contextAccessor
    }
    
    fun someOtherMethod() {
        mContextAccessor?.getAppContext()?.let { nonNullContext ->
            // use nonNullContext here
            extractedHi = nonNullContext.hi; // i get error here!
        }
    }
}
```

And this class in my project:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements  MyActivity.ContextAccessor {
    
    private SomeLibraryClass someLibraryClassInstance = SomeLibraryClass();

    public String hi = "hi";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ContextAccessor reference is set to some library class
        someLibraryClassInstance.setContextAccessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Super important!
        someLibraryClassInstance.setContextAccessor(null);
        // OR create some method like `someLibraryClassInstance.removeContextAccessor(this)`
    }

    @Override
    public Application getApplicationContext() {
        return super.getApplication();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `Application` and `MyActivity.ContextAccessor`? I don't see how do these things tie together.

Comment: @al3c Well, I'm just following this answer's advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63206457/13976983 He's not answering, so I decided to ask a question here.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you enlighten me. Because I'm lost. I can't see how they tie together either :(

Comment: `getApplicationContext` returns an Application. I don't know what application looks like, you didn't post the source. You want that to have a property named `hi` I see an activity that has a `hi` public filed, but that isn't related to anything, that should be a getter called `getHi` and be part of some interface at least.

Comment: @al3c I think I almost understand. But, please, because Im a beginner, can you write a full answer with code? thank

Comment: I simply want toretrieve "hi" from my library'

Comment: @Brandy I can't write a full answer because I don't know what is that you're trying to achieve. Given the partial code here, It seems you want to pass a String from an Activity to some class. And that class is created inside the Activity. If that's the case just add it as a constructor parameter of your class.

Comment: please see my original question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204657/access-main-project-from-module-in-android-studio/

Comment: @al3c see here thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `hi` property to the `ContextAccessor` interface:

```
interface ContextAccessor {

    val hi: String
    // ...
}
```

And in `MyActivity` implement `getHi()` method:

```
@NotNull
@Override
public String getHi() {
    return hi;
}
```

In your library class `SomeLibraryClass` you can access to it like the following:

```
var extractedHi: String? = null

fun someOtherMethod() {
    extractedHi = mContextAccessor?.hi
}
```

Comment: ok but i get the same issue https://i.imgur.com/8Z6hjlR.png

Comment: try `nonNullContext.hi`, bcz it's a property

Comment: hm, you should do it like this: `mContextAccessor?.hi`